# Sort-Object and Integers

Tags: sorting, powershell

I am trying to sort a colomn with numbers in a CSV file. But somehow it doesn't work. Sample CSV:

```
Orange;65
Red;160
Green;140
White;110
Purple;85
```

This is the piece of code I tried it with:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Header "Color", "Number" -delimiter ';' data.csv
$csv | Sort-Object Number
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
Color                Number
-----                ------
White                110
Green                140
Red                  160
Orange               65
Purple               85
```

Obviously not in the correct order. Can someone please explain me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`Import-CSV` imports csv columns as `strings` by default. You need to cast it to `int` before you can sort by value, and not "alphabetical". Ex:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Header "Color", "Number" -delimiter ';' data.csv
$csv | % { $_.Number = [int]$_.Number }
$csv | Sort-Object Number

Color  Number
-----  ------
Orange     65
Purple     85
White     110
Green     140
Red       160
```

As an alternative, you can cast it while sorting, like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Header "Color", "Number" -delimiter ';' data.csv
$csv | Sort-Object @{e={$_.Number -as [int]}}
```

or even shorter `$csv | Sort-Object { [int]$_.Number }`

Comment: Cheers mate got that sorted out :)

Comment: Could you explain me though, from your alternative, what does the @{e= mean? Especially the 'e'. Sorry to bother you, I'm still learning :)

Comment: expression. it's something you use to specify properties in powershell. Example to create custom field in `select-object`: `select-object @{name="displayedname";expression={code to produce value using ex $_.property etc.} }`.  `Sort-Object` doesn't need a columnname to sort, so I just used expression.

Comment: read more about "calculated properties" at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx

Comment: Took me forever to find a cast as sorting example. Wish this was on TechNet! (and not just the string expression example) Thanks!

Comment: @ScriptingBerry The `e` in `@{e={$_.Number -as [int]}}` is the key "expression" truncated to just an "e". Powershell, in generall, automatically tries to infer which _name_ is referred to by checking if there is enough information provided that there is one, and only one, match in the set of available _names_ based on the context. A _name_ can, for example, be a parameter-name to a CmdLet or a property-name of an object. There is, as usual, none or very little documentation on this since Microsoft don't think documentation is important.

Comment: @StuartBranham me too :-D

Comment: The first thingie is a hashtable, and the second thingie is a scriptblock.

`$a = @{e={$_.Number -as [int]}};
$a.gettype();

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object

;$b =  { [int]$_.Number };
$b.gettype();

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ScriptBlock                              System.Object`